# How to detect ActiveState version of perl?

Tags: perl, activestate

One of [my CPAN modules](http://metacpan.org/pod/Forks::Super) is [not available](https://code.activestate.com/ppm/Forks-Super/) on ActivePerl through its `ppm` utility. Apparently my unit testing for this module is too thorough and [ActiveState's build process times out](http://ppm4.activestate.com/MSWin32-x64/5.22/2200/M/MO/MOB/Forks-Super-0.80.d/log-20151008T060111.txt?_ga=1.82449681.683374651.1462382483) when it attempts to build it.

So what I would like to do in my tests is to detect when my module is being built on ActivePerl, and if so, to provide the build process with a smaller and faster set of tests.

[One way I've found to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511599/why-do-i-get-an-extra-newline-in-the-middle-of-a-utf-8-character-with-xmlparse/2511904#2511904) is:

```
($is_activestate) = grep /provided by ActiveState/, qx($^X -v)
```

but I'm wondering if there is a more lightweight option. An environment variable that is always (and only) set in ActivePerl? Something in [`Config`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Config)? Any other suggestions?

**UPDATE:** Looks like [`$ENV{ACTIVESTATE_PPM_BUILD}`](http://ppm4.activestate.com/MSWin32-x86-64int/5.22/2200/M/MO/MOB/Forks-Super-0.82.d/log-20160511T001811.txt?_ga=1.58528301.683374651.1462382483) is set during these builds.

Comment: FWIW: `Config::local_patches()` may be of some value.  On my machine it returns `ActivePerl Build 2201 [299574]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checking if it's running under an ActivePerl build is not optimal. Ideally, you want to check if it's running in ActiveState's build environment. I would dump the env in `t/00-use.t` to see if they set some variable indicating this.

```
info("$_=$ENV{$_}") for sort keys %ENV;
```

You could also contact ActiveState and ask them what they recommend.

---

Alternatively, you could make it so the slowest tests only run on demand (e.g. when a certain environment is present). 5 minutes of testing might seem a bit excessive to others as well.

---

As for checking if you're running an ActiveState build, here are some possibilities:

- `use Config; print Config::local_patches();` returns a string that includes `ActivePerl Build`.
- `$Config{cf_email}` is set to `support@ActiveState.com`
- The ActivePerl::Config module exists.
- The ActivePerl::PPM module exists.

Could always check all of them.

```
use Config qw( %Config );

my $is_activeperl = 0;
$is_activeperl ||= eval { Config::local_patches() =~ /ActivePerl/i };
$is_activeperl ||= $Config{cf_email} =~ /ActiveState/i;
$is_activeperl ||= eval { require ActivePerl::Config };
$is_activeperl ||= eval { require ActivePerl::PPM };
```

Comment: These are all great suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

According to a quick search for `activeperl ppm build increase timeout` you can report this situation to their mailing list/support and they will manually increase timeout value for builds of your module.